# SQL Server Insert into linked server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, linked-server

In a procedure I control errors with `TRY` `CATCH`, but in an insert into linked server not runs for handling this errors, because try catch not run.

How I can handling this errors?

Example:

```
insert into linkedserver.database.dbo.table values ('value1','value2')
```

If the server isoffline I have error of connection of the `SQLCLI` and cannot control this error for insert in local when the linked server are offline for after when the server return to online status put the data in the remote server with another procedure.

Thanks

Jorge

Comment: You talk about "when the server return to online status" - why not build a solution that *always* assumes that the server is unavailable right now, and applies the change when the server is available. Something like Service Broker would handle this, and you'd no longer have any dependency on the remote server.

Comment: Please be aware that tags stand alone.  That is, selecting the tags `linked` and `server` doesn't mean you're talking about the linked server feature in SQL Server.

Answer (score 1):

if you wrap your code into a EXEC statment you will have access to the error.

```
like exec( 'insert into....')
```